# Using s3 getObject in Lambda function generates url with InvalidToken error

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, lambda, serverless-framework

I'm trying to get presigned URL to s3 object using getObject method in Lambda function. But result URL displays an InvalidToken error when I open it in browser.

I have uploaded a `data.txt` file to a bucket.

**content.ts**

```
import 'source-map-support/register';
import { APIGatewayProxyHandler } from 'aws-lambda';
import { S3 } from 'aws-sdk';

const s3 = new S3({
    signatureVersion: 'v4'
});

export const getContent: APIGatewayProxyHandler = async (event, context) => {
    const signedUrl = s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', {
        Bucket: process.env.BUCKET,
        Key: 'data.txt',
        Expires: 60
    });

    return {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify({
            url: signedUrl
        })
    };
}
```

**serverless.yml**

```
service:
  name: purchased-content

custom:
  bucket: "project-paid-content"

plugins:
  - serverless-webpack

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs10.x
  region: us-east-2
  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: "Allow"
      Action:
       - "s3:GetObject"
      Resource:
        - "arn:aws:s3:::${self:custom.bucket}"
        - "arn:aws:s3:::${self:custom.bucket}/*"

functions:
  getContent:
    handler: content.getContent
    events:
      - http:
          method: get
          path: get
    environment:
      BUCKET: ${self:custom.bucket}

resources:
  Resources:
    PaidContentBucket:
      Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
      Properties:
        BucketName: ${self:custom.bucket}
        AccessControl: Private
```

Comment: Where does your code run (inside AWS or outside of AWS)?

Comment: It is an AWS Lambda function. How in the world would it run outside AWS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your IAM policies seem ok. I think the problem might be with the response.

```
return {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify({
            url: signedUrl
        })
    };
```

Why are you trying to stringify the url returned. This should be directly used. 
Try logging the returned url and using that. If that fails you might want to look at IAM policies/roles further.

Comment: API Gateway expects that the returned body to be always stringified: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/malformed-502-api-gateway/